# Send an invitation to attendees' email through Spreadsheet and Google Calendar API

Tags: google-sheets, events, notifications, calendar, google-calendar-api

First of all, I don't have any coding knowledge/background, so I don't know if it is appropriate to ask for advices here, and also this is my first post here. I usually look for some codes on the internet that could find my needs, update it to fit my data and done.

So, right now I am setting a shared platform in my organization to allow people to register as either a presenter or participant of sharing sessions.

The session are all pre-created, and they have to pick in the list. After registering, the data are available in a spreadsheet and I have the code to add these registered person for the sessions.

However my issue is, they are added as guests of the event, but don't receive an invitation for this event. Here is the script:

```
function Presenterscalendar() {
  var cal,i,iCalId,row,sheet,thisEvent,presenter,title,email;

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Presenters");
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("A2:G1000");
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  cal = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();

  for (i in data) {
    row = data[i];
    presenter = row[1];
    title = row[3];
    tstart = row[2];
    iCalId = row[4];
    email = row[6];

    thisEvent = cal.getEventSeriesById(iCalId);

    if (thisEvent) {
      thisEvent.setTitle(title);
      thisEvent.setDescription('A session presented by '+presenter);
      thisEvent.addGuest(email)


    }
 }
}
```

I looked for other script in order to send the invitations to all attendees of each session in the calendar:

```
function sendInvite(calendarId, eventId, email) {
  var calendarId = 'test@test.com';
  var vss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var vS = vss.getSheetByName('Presenters');
  var dataRange = vS.getRange("A2:H1000");
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  for (i in data) {
    row = data[i];
    presenter = row[1];
    title = row[3];
    tstart = row[1];
    iCalId = row[4];
    mail = row[6];


  var eventId = vS.getRange("e2:e1000").getValue();
  var eid = eventId.split("@")[0]; // Added;
  var event = Calendar.Events.get(calendarId, eid);
  var attendees = event.attendees;
   if(event.attendees) {
    event.attendees.push({
      email: email
    });
  } else {
    event.attendees = new Array({email:email});
  }
  event = Calendar.Events.patch(event, calendarId, eid, {
    sendupdates: "all"
  });
}
}
```

This works if I just put a static email for ex ({email:"test@google.com"}), but when kept as is it says "missing attendees mail". Eventually, what I would like to is either:

- The script to get all the events in the calendar and send the notifications to new attendees registered (update)
- The script to get the data from the spreadsheet (where I have in 1 column the email of the attendee -1 row = 1 attendee-) and send the notification to new attendees

I did allow Calendar API for the script and the Google Cloud platform already.

I wonder if you could help me on this, I tried to replicate what I found on the internet, but my limited knowledge on coding doesn't allow me to go further...

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Yes, your question is about coding, so appropriate and welcome here. Welcome to Stack Overflow. If ever in doubt: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

### The [optional query parameters for an event patch](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/patch?apix_params=%7B%22calendarId%22%3A%22primary%22%2C%22eventId%22%3A%22tg4m0b5q6jbjq1bca2n1bkslk4%22%2C%22resource%22%3A%7B%22summary%22%3A%22cccdefg%22%7D%7D#request) are case sensitive

Thus, you need to modify

```js
    sendupdates: "all"
```

to

```js
    sendUpdates: "all"
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the correction it defintely was an issue. However, after editing, I still have this issue: "GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to calendar.events.patch failed with error: Missing attendee email." And I defintely have some emails in my first 2 sessions.
How wrong I am with the code ?
Thanks !

Comment: What about logging `email` before passing it to `Calendar.Events.patch` to check its value?

Comment: Hi, I don't know if this is what you asked, but I just added 'Logger.log(email)' before 'Calendar.Events.patch' and in the Execution log, it showed "null".

Comment: That's exactly what I meant - if `email` is `null`, this means that you are not passing an attendee. How do you call funciton `sendInvite(calendarId, eventId, email) ` and pass the `email` parameter to it?

Comment: Yes I believe that is the question. What ideally I would like to have is for each event in the calendar, "scan" the list of email of the attendees, and everytime there is a new attendee, the sendinvite function will notify him/her of the event. I guess I am right now asking for the solution without trying to solve the problem by myself? If so, then I'll try more